# How to compare 2 arrays, return the keys from matches from the array to rewrite the keys in first array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 Arrays:

```
const firstArray = ["A", "B", "1", "2", "F", "89", "8", "K"];
const inputArray = ["1", "B", "F", "A", "89"];
```

And with

```
for (const index of firstArray.keys()) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

I get the keys from my Array: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

And with

```
for (const index of inputArray .keys()) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

I get the keys from my input array: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

I use this to compare and check if all elements are in firstArray:

```
const foundedArray = inputArray.filter(element => firstArray.includes(element));
```

All fine till here, but now I need to get the keys from firstArray into my inputArray that they fit to the same matching values from firstArray.

I need get the keys from firstArray into my input array:

```
Value ["1", "B", "F", "A", "89"];
Keys    2,   1,   4,   0,   5
```

Im stucking here how can I write this.

playground: https://jsfiddle.net/alaber/u792gdfa/

thank you!

Comment: Do you just want to get the indices or are you actually trying to sort inputArray based on firstArray?

Comment: (also, what happens if an element appears more than once?..)

Comment: Hi Jonas, yes i try to reorder the input array based on firstArray keys. @briosheje If an element appears more then once it should just return the elements with the indicies from firstArray for sorting.

Comment: @JosephineDone so it should return an array, right?

Comment: what do you mean with *"order"*? please add the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz please see the last example, thats what I need at the end. briosheje yes, I need an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting a reordered array, you could count the values of `inputArray` and filter `firstArray` by checking the leftover count and decrement the count.

```js
const
    firstArray = ["A", "B", "1", "2", "F", "89", "8", "K"],
    inputArray = ["1", "B", "F", "A", "89"],
    count = inputArray.reduce((count, value) => {
        count[value] = (count[value] || 0) + 1;
        return count;
    }, {}),
    result = firstArray.filter(value => count[value] && count[value]--);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  inputArray.map(it => firstArray.indexOf(it))
```

Using `indexOf` you can get the position of a certain value innthe array.

Comment: <pres>const sortHelper = (a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : b > a ? 1 : 0);

const getKeys = inputArray.map(it => firstArray.indexOf(it)).sort(sortHelper);
console.log("thats their keys in first_Array: " + getKeys);</pres> Works!